# How can the inexact differential equation $y' = \frac{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2}{1+(x-\frac{1}{2}x^2)y^2}$ be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Since this equation is of the form $y' = \frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$, I tried computing the partials $M_y$, $N_x$, $\frac{M_y - N_x}{N(x,y)}$ and $\frac{N_x - M_y}{M(x,y)}$ - unfortunately, all of these expressions are functions of $x$ and $y$. In particular, $M_y \neq N_x$, so the equation is inexact but clearly, the methods used to solve inexact differential equations aren't applicable here either as I don't know how to find the relevant integrating factor.

Wolfram Alpha gives the "standard computation time exceeded" message.

I've also tried various substitutions but I'm now stumped. Are there any alternative approaches? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried using an integrating factor?

Comment: I don't know how to compute it, as $\frac{M_y - N_x}{N(x,y)}$ and $\frac{N_x - M_y}{M(x,y)}$ are both functions of $x$ and $y$, and I'm not very confident with solving inexact DEs.

Comment: Where did you get this question from? Is this an exercise for a class?

Comment: It's from a physics problem that I'm working on (outside of class)

Comment: Could you add the context of your problem? For many cases if WA can’t solve it, no human can. Perhaps there’s an error in your derivation.